# Update div dynamically onclick

Tags: jquery

I want to change the border of a box dynamically by clicking on the box.

Here is my HTML for two boxes:

```
<div id="twoBoxes">

    <div class="box1"  style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red" onclick="addBorder('box1')"></div>
    <br />
    <div class="box2" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:yellow" onclick="addBorder('box2')"></div>

</div>
```

And here is the function addBorder

```
function addBorder (sq) {
        chosenSquare = sq;
        $('.' + chosenSquare).css("border", "black solid 4px");



}
```

So what is happening is on the page there are two boxes, and if I click one of them, it will add that border to it. Or, it should but nothing is happening

What I've tried:

-I've tried changing the `class = box1` to `id` (for both)
-I've tried console logs to see if it is in storing the correct information, which it is. `chosenSquare` saves as the class name of the box chosen

I've tried doing an "`addClass()`" instead of `".css()"`

It seems that the div just does not want to change dynamically on the fly when I click it.

For reference, here is what it is currently (not) doing:

https://jsfiddle.net/hh5u5dLa/

Could someone help me with this?? Am I missing something??

Comment: [It appears to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/4u57g8xc/). I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: @stryner hm how very strange. I copy and pasted what I included her into fiddle but it doesn't work for me...https://jsfiddle.net/hh5u5dLa/

Comment: You have to change the Javascript settings to "No wrap - in <head>". Otherwise it will put your function in an Onload function, which means it will no longer be globally scoped. (You also need to include jQuery)

Comment: @Stryner wonder if it is a character issue. maybe one of the ' is acting up

Comment: @Stryner ah ok thanks. and I forgot to change it to jquery. I don't know why this works on jsfiddle but not in my code.